# How to add Task name in resources sheet?

Tags: project-management, microsoft-project-2010

Gantt Chart Resource Usage, shows the Resource name, is there a way to show the task name ?
for example:

[image: example]

How to show the parent task name ?
example, Review 1 belongs to Task X, Review 2 belongs to Task Y...
I can't find this field in the available fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Resource Usage view insert the field "Task Summary Name".

[image]